# Magento 2: How to additonalClasses for Tab in form ui component?

Tags: magento2, uicomponent

i try this code but it not working with tab in form ui component:

```
<item name="additionalClasses" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="my-custom-class" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
</item>
```

Comment: what you want to exactly?

Comment: i want add class to my custom tab in form ui component?

Comment: Do you want to additionClass for form filed or left side custom tab?

Comment: left side custom tab

Answer (score 1):

Try this code to add additonalclasses for tab in form ui component.

More information in details, Visit, [How to additonalClasses for Tab in Magento 2 UI component form](https://magentodev.in/how-to-additonalclasses-for-tab-in-magento-2-ui-component-form/)

```
<fieldset name="address" sortOrder="30">
     <settings>
        <additionalClasses>
            <class name="custom-address">true</class>
        </additionalClasses>
    </settings>
</fieldset>
```

Hope this helps. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try using following example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <fieldset name="websites" sortOrder="30">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="additionalClasses" xsi:type="string">admin__field-medium</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: It does not working with Magento 2.3 :(

Comment: This is tested code in 2.3 :) Makesure you use this correctly

Comment: I tried it but nothing happened

Comment: Your answer is right @SohelRana but it's for form filed... it want for custom left tab

Comment: yes, I apologize for not clarifying

Comment: Show your full xml